# Divide all row values of specific columns in pandas to have a rowsum of 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which a number of subcolumns, who should match up to a total row sum of 1:

```
columnA  columnB columnC columnD columnE
A         1        0        0      10
B         1        1        0      15
C         0        0        1      10
...
```

where the `columnB, columnC, columnD` should sumup to 1:

```
columnA  columnB columnC columnD columnE
A         1        0        0      10
B         0.5      0.5      0      15
C         0        0        1      10
...
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide by sum only selected columns:

```
c = ['columnB','columnC','columnD']

df[c] = df[c].div(df[c].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
  columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD  columnE
0       A      1.0      0.0      0.0       10
1       B      0.5      0.5      0.0       15
2       C      0.0      0.0      1.0       10
```

Test with all values `1`:

```
print (df)
  columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD  columnE
0       A        1        1        1       10
1       B        1        1        0       15
2       C        0        0        1       10

c = ['columnB','columnC','columnD']

df[c] = df[c].div(df[c].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
  columnA   columnB   columnC   columnD  columnE
0       A  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333       10
1       B  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000       15
2       C  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000       10
```